# Fedex Configuration "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us"

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, shopping-cart, fedex

I configured the fedex in magento 2 but it gives this error always.
[image]

I might have entered some data incorrectly I need help configuring it.

[image]